# How to make a simple bar chart using d3 and pulling data from firebase

Tags: javascript, d3.js, firebase

I was going through the d3 tutorial of creating bar charts. I was able to recreate it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S7Lty/27/). Now, I want to pull data from firebase and plot it using the same code. This is what my code looks like:

**JS**

```
new Firebase('https://crossfilteralpha.firebaseIO.com')
    .on('value', function (snapshot) {

    var data = snapshot.val()

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
        .range([0, 420]);

    d3.select(".chart")
        .selectAll("div")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("div")
        .style("width", function (d) {
        return x(d) + "px";
    })
        .text(function (d) {
        return d;
    });
}
```

**CSS**

```
.chart div {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    background-color: steelblue;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 1px;
    color: white;
    clear: left;
}
```

I know something is really wrong cause I dont understand fully how pulling data from firebase works. Help appreciated. Let me know if you need more info.